# Can i use M language from power bi/power query on javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, npm, powerbi, powerquery

I´m trying to use the 'applied steps' from power query inside a javascript function.

The power query function:

```
let
    Fonte = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\INTEL\Downloads\Planilha  POWER BI SPC.xlsx"), null, true),
    Geral_Sheet = Fonte{[Item="Geral",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Cabeçalhos Promovidos" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Geral_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Cabeçalhos Promovidos","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"ID", "Nome", "IP", "porta", "SN", "MAC", "Modelo", "TIpo", "Máx. Canais"}),
    #"Preenchido Abaixo" = Table.FillDown(#"Valor Substituído",{"ID", "Nome", "IP", "porta", "SN", "MAC", "Modelo", "TIpo", "Máx. Canais"})
in
    #"Preenchido Abaixo"
```

I want to use this inside this function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

/* load 'fs' for readFile and writeFile support */
import * as fs from 'fs';
XLSX.set_fs(fs);

import { Readable } from 'stream';
XLSX.stream.set_readable(Readable);

@Injectable()
export class TablesTreatmentService {
  async getTable(table: string) {
    const url = process.env.WOORKBOOK_URL;

    const data = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer();

    const sheet = XLSX.read(data).Sheets[table];

    return XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
  }
}
```

somebody knows hows to implements this? if there´s any package or anything?